# Detect support for HTML5 iframe sandbox attribute

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, iframe, sandbox

Does anyone know how to detect if the iframe sandbox attribute is supported by the browser without relaying on version checks, etc?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can check whether an `iframe` element has the `sandbox` attribute:

```
var sandboxSupported = "sandbox" in document.createElement("iframe");
```

---

**Side note**

A good way to find feature detects is to look at [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) and see if it has one already. This is the [Modernizr code for the sandbox attribute test](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/blob/master/feature-detects/iframe-sandbox.js):

```
Modernizr.addTest('sandbox', 'sandbox' in document.createElement('iframe'));
```

Alternatively (if you need to use lots of feature detects in your app) include Modernizr and use it properly, instead of just getting ideas from its source!

Answer (score -1):

The fastest way to check the new **HTML5** features supported by your browser, check this link [HTML5Test](http://html5test.com) and for **CSS3** features check this link [CSS3Test](http://css3test.com).
The cool thing is that you can compare the shown result to other browsers at the same page.